# Limiting the size of inbound buffer in netty 4 cr6

Tags: netty

How can I limit the size of inbound buffers that are being created by netty when client sends large files? I want a client to stop sending data over the network when ByteBuf is full and resume once it becomes ready to receive more data.

Here is my handler code:

```
public class MyDecoder extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    // limit the size of recieving buffer to 1024
    ctx.channel().config().setRecvByteBufAllocator(new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(1024));
    }

@Override public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageList<Object> msgs) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf byteBuf = msgs.<ByteBuf>cast().get(0);
    // stop after this line in debugger to check size of the actual payload per messageReceived invocation
    int bufferSize = byteBuf.readableBytes();
    }
}
```

Now suppose that in my test I write:

```
EmbeddedChannel ch = new EmbeddedChannel(new MyDecoder());
ch.writeInbound(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(<<<here is a byte representation of a large file, say 100 mb>>>));
ch.readInbound(); // etc...
```

Now when in debugger I get to a line where bufferSize is calculated, I always get the full size of my large file. The only difference FixedRecvByteBufAllocator makes at that point is when its size is set to 0 - all other values yield same results.

In netty 4 cr2 there was a method that served that purpose, newInboundBuffer, but there is no such construct in cr6 and onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FixedRecvByteBufAllocator should limit the buffer to max 1024 bytes if this is not the case its a bug.